# How do I specify a where clause that says that a passed type's reference can be converted to another one in Rust?

Tags: rust, where-clause, traits

I need to express that a reference to a certain type parameter can be converted to a reference to another one.

Example:

```rust
trait TestTrait {}

struct TestStruct {}

impl TestTrait for TestStruct {}

fn test<Trait: ?Sized, Type>(object: &Type) -> &Trait
    where ... 
{
    object
}

fn call_test()
{
    let object = TestStruct{};

    let t = test::<dyn TestTrait, TestStruct>(&object);
}
```

What do I need to put in the where clause?

EDIT: I don't want to be implementing From, AsRef, etc. I've considered those.

Comment: IIUC, you want `where Type: Into<&Trait>` or maybe `where &Type: Into<&Trait>`

Comment: @jmb I've tried that but you need to implement From for that to work, and call 'into()' for the conversion. I'd like to avoid those if possible.

Comment: Just `Type: Trait`? Then you can return `object as &dyn Trait`.

Comment: @isaactfa Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On nightly, you can use [`Unsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html):

```rust
#![feature(unsize)]

fn test<Trait: ?Sized, Type>(object: &Type) -> &Trait
where
    Type: std::marker::Unsize<Trait>,
{
    object
}
```

Note that this will also accept other coercions, e.g. arrays to slices.

On stable, I don't think there is a way to achieve that.

Comment: Works on nightly. Hope they stabilize it soon.

Comment: @chila Actually, `Unsize` is never intended to be stabilized as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want [`std::convert::AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html)?

```rust
fn test<Trait: ?Sized, Type>(object: &Type) -> &Trait
    where Type: AsRef<Trait>,
{
    object.as_ref()
}
```

Note though that you can't take traits as type parameters.

Comment: That is an option I considered, but I thought I could do it without implementing AsRef, From, etc. I'll edit my question to note that. If there's no way, I'll use From probably on the references. It expresses the semantic better.

Comment: @chila AsRef allows for implicit reference conversion, you don't have to call a `.into()` / `.as_ref()` method. Even if you do explicitly call the method, it'll be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: If I don't call `.as_ref` it gives me "mismatched types" error inside the function. If I don't implement `AsRef<TestTrait> for TestStruct`, the compiler says that the trait bound `TestStruct: AsRef<dyn TestTrait>` is not satisfied, so I need to implement it for every type I want to pass.